# Elastic search aggregation with sort

Tags: elasticsearch

How to use sort with aggregation?
Here is my request, but response isn't sorted.

```
{
  "from":0,
  "size":4,
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":[
        {
          "match":{
            "currentStatus":"published"
          }
        },
        {
          "match":{
            "type":"time_and_material"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort":[
    {
      "createdAt":{
        "order":"desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How request must bee look like?

Comment: No aggregation has been used in example  given above

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have any aggregation in it, but here is an example of how to do what you need: you put an `order` clause within the aggregation.  Here is a sample.

```
GET devdev/redemption/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "a1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "output.success",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```